# Admin View Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Seguinte eu criei um site utilizando *Ruby on Rails* e as gems **Devise** e **Pundit**. Os usuários possuem uma ***role*** que pode ser Analista, Desenvolvedor ou Administrador.

Estou usando uma *View* para listar todos os usuários cadastrados para o administrador.

Este é o meu *Controller*:

```
def users_list
  @users = User.order(:id).page params[:page]
  authorize @users
end
```

Esta é minha *View*:

```
<%- model_class = User -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize.titleize %></h1>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:id) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:email) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:role) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:created_at) %></th>
      <th><%=t '.actions', :default => t("helpers.actions") %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to user.id, edit_user_registration_path(user) %></td>
        <td><%= user.email %></td>
        <td><%= user.role %></td>
        <td><%=l user.created_at %></td>
        <td>

          <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                      cancel_user_registration_path(user),
                      :method => :delete,
                      :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')) },
                      :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= link_to t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new")),
            new_user_registration_path,
            :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Como eu poderia fazer para que fosse possível alterar a *Role* do usuário nesta mesma *View* de listagem de usuários ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de um elemento td adicionei e modifiquei a action update no UsersController para aceitar o parâmetro :role

```
<td>
 <%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
   <%= f.select(:role, User.roles.keys.map {|role| [role.titleize,role]}) %>
   <%= f.submit 'Change Role', :class => "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
 <%end%>
</td>
```